# Having trouble with a jar file I have created

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have created a class file where there are some methods which I need to use in other projects. I have tried to "export" the file and create a "JAR file" and there is no problem until this point.

I have tried to import the "JAR file" in another project and I used te command "Build Path".

The problem is that when I create the class object which is into the JAR File I cannot use any methods I have built for that object.

Can anyone help me, please ?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What exact error do you see? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Did you make your methods public? Are you sure it is on your classpath? Maybe try adding some screenshots to add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour you will find in the Eclipse tool.

Whenever you import a jar what Eclipse does is that it creates project structure that has been specified in your jar.

So what happens then is that you would get the project structure only but no classes inside it what you have to do is you have to manually create all your java files again. That is the inherient behaviour of Eclipse when you import any jar

Comment: So how does he do what he wants to do?

Comment: i am afraid he would have to redo the stuff again may be copy the files from previous project and put those again and recreate a jar